# Convexification of facility location problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, computational-geometry

I have a set of service locations $\{ {\bf{x}}_i \in \mathbb{R}^2\}_{i = 1}^{N}$.
I have $k$ facilities to locate in a way that distance of each service point to the nearest facility is minimized.

My model is building "circles" around the facilities and minimize the radius of the circle while constraining that each service location is within at least one facility radius:

$$ \min \| {\bf{r}} \|_{\infty} $$

subject to

$$ \forall i \min_k \| {\bf{x}}_{i} - {\bf{c}}_{k} \| \leq {r}_{k}  $$

Where $\bf{r} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ is the vector of all $k$ radii of around the facilities and ${\bf{c}}_{k}$ is the location of the $k$ facility.
The should mean that each "service point" is within the radius of its nearest facility.

The formulation above isn't convex as those choice of ${r}_{k}$ is a function of the left side.
Is there a way to convexify this? Or other similar in the spirit convex solution?

The idea is building a service radius around each facility.

Comment: If your objective is to minimize $\max_k r_k$, you can minimize $r$ and replace $r_k$ with $r$ in the constraint.

Comment: @RobPratt, I am aware it is not convex as mentioned. The motivation is looking for a convex formulation which approximates the concept of the solution.

Comment: I meant to say that the problem is already convex if $N=1$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem

Comment: @RobPratt, appreciate the link. I was aware of that. (K = 1, not N = 1).